# Magento error in catalog manage product: Source model not found for attribute

Tags: admin, error, product-attribute, source-model

I am facing error in **magento/admin** `catalog > manage product> and product.`

when I am trying to open Product its giving error :

> There has been an error processing your request
>   Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.
>   Error log record number: 1102395163076

I am seeing this error only in **Catalog >products**.

I checked error report in **var>report**, this is what it says:

```
    a:5:{i:0;s:110:"Source model "temando/entity_attribute_source_packaging_mode" not found for attribute "temando_packaging_mode"";i:1;s:3814:"#0 /home/cluster-sites/4157/e/eponaforge.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(387): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "t...')
#1 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2 public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Attributes.php(70): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Array)
#3 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#4 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tabs.php(79): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#7 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#8 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'product_tabs')
#9 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'product_tabs')
#10 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#11 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#12 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#13 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#14 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(Array, true, true)
#15 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(207): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout(Array)
#16 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->newAction()
#17 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('new')
#18 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#19 /public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#20 /public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#22 {main}";s:3:"url";s:92:"/index.php/admin/catalog_product/new/set/4/type/simple/key/4beccee60930382af9537cd1010c4f7a/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
```

Comment: Did you edited your database ?

Comment: no.. i did not edit anything in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have missing class file

```
Namespace_Temando_Entity_Attribute_Source_Packaging_Mod
```

Check if Mod.php exist in your Temando module folder.

This file is used by the attribute temando_packaging_mode and it is not able to find in your module.

Comment: i already removed temando extension. so this error coming bcz of that extension... i removed the extension and cleared the cache....

Comment: Ok than you need to remove temando_packaging_mode attribute also

Comment: You can delete it from Catalog -> Attribute -> Manage Attributes section in admin

Comment: unable to delete the temando attributes... its not deleting

Comment: what error it is showing? you can delete it from eav_attribute table from database as well

Answer (score 1):

So this happens because there is an attribute with the source model `temando/entity_attribute_source_packaging_mode`. When you remove this module it does not remove the attributes created by the module.

The way I normally do this is have a project specific setup module `Project_Setup`. This module is simply a bunch of set-up scripts for adding/removing attributes etc. What you can do is make a module and a setup script that simply removes the attribute `temando_packaging_mode` and anything else that has been added by the other module.